# execute awk in loop inside Python script

Tags: python, linux, csv, awk

I have a tabular file with 15 columns, and I want to execute 2 awk commands in a loop for each row of that file (and I'm making a lot of other functions in a python script, so these awk commands should be inside my script.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import csv


strand_signature = "awk '{if($10 > $11) {$16='-'}; else {$16='+'}}' row"
strand_correction = "awk '{n1=$10;n2=$11;if($10 > $11) {$10=n2; $11=n1}' row"


with open('my_file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv_reader:
        subprocess.call(strand_signature, shell=True)
        subprocess.call(strand_correction, shell=True)
        print(row)
```

Briefly: each command that I want to execute are stored in 2 variables: strand_signature and strand_correction. So I read my csv file row by row and call both scripts, but, in my print test, the modifications don't occur.

Can anyone explain-me in which point I make a mistake?

Comment: such approach is not efficient: either make all processing in python OR all the processing in awk script

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to write a script is to write individual lines or even just parts of lines, running, testing, making sure it works, and then continuing to the next part. That way, you only ever have a couple of issues to fix at a time.

You have instead chosen the most difficult way possible: writing the whole script, and then trying to fix all the problems afterwards. This means that you have to account for all the following issues *simultaneously*, as every one is a complete showstopper:

1. Your first awk command is syntactically invalid because you're trying to nest single quotes in single quotes without quoting or escaping them.
2. Your second awk command is syntactically invalid because it's missing a `}`
3. Neither awk command outputs anything
4. You specify `row` as the filename for `awk`, even though this is a Python list and not a file
5. You never read or write any Python data from or to `awk`
6. Even if you did, `awk` is line based, not Python list based, so you'd have to join and split accordingly

The best option is to throw out all the `awk` and use Python instead. This is much easier, more robust, and way faster to both write and run:

```
with open('my_file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv_reader:
        if float(row[9]) > float(row[10]):
            row[15] = "-"
        else:
            row[15] = "+"
        # ...
        print(row)
```